# How to use "else if" with the preprocessor #ifdef?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

In my project the program can do one thing of two, but never both, so I decided that the best i can do for one class is to define it depending of a #define preprocessor variable. The next code can show you my idea, but you can guess that it does not work:

```
#ifdef CALC_MODE
typedef MyCalcClass ChosenClass;
#elifdef USER_MODE
typedef MyUserClass ChosenClass;
#else
static_assert(false, "Define CALC_MODE or USER_MODE");
#endif
```

So i can do

```
#define CALC_MODE
```

right before this.

I can resign the use of `static_assert` if needed. How to do this?

Comment: You can use `#if defined(CALC_MODE)` and `#elif defined(USER_MODE)`

Comment: Are you looking for [`$elif defined(...)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/conditional)? You may also find the [`#error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/error) directive interesting.

Comment: @RetiredNinja that is correct!

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Right, actually better than static_assert in this case, because it will always be false

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's a suggestion, based largely on comments posted to your question:

```cpp
#if defined(CALC_MODE)
    typedef MyCalcClass ChosenClass;
#elif defined(USER_MODE)
    typedef MyUserClass ChosenClass;
#else
    #error "Define CALC_MODE or USER_MODE"
#endif
```

Comment: `defined` is an operator, not a function, like `sizeof`, so the parentheses are unnecessary and are just clutter. It is better that students see it is an operator that directs the compiler to do something rather than that it is a function that is called.

Comment: @Eric It's a Community Wiki, so feel free to edit. However, I think you'll find a near 50:50 split on the use of `sizeof Eric` *versus* `sizeof(Eric)`.

Comment: Yeah, definitely not cut-and-dry. I personally always use parens on `sizeof` and `defined`, just because it looks a lot cleaner in my mind. There are lots of folks in both camps.

Comment: I've done most of my programming on the Windows platform using Microsoft tools and code, so maybe I've picked up [their habits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-if-hash-elif-hash-else-and-hash-endif-directives-c-cpp?view=msvc-160).

Comment: you forget about say `sizeof(int)` . you can't do this no-braces way haha

Answer (score 2):

`#elifdef` and `#elifndef` are officially supported since [C23](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/conditional) and [C++23](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/conditional).

But these standards are not yet released (as of July 2023) and the new features are not yet widely adopted by compilers, so you are still better off with `#if defined()` for now.